# Unidentified Component and RefDes EC

Tags: pcb

I am trying to identify components with RefDes EC1 and EC2 in this circuit (the boxes at the top with markings 100-10Z). I have done a lot of searching and EC is not even an accepted RefDes EC.

I think the component might be a SMT Inductor, but I don't really know.

[image: PCB]

Answer (score 2):

I  believe they are electrolytic capacitors with a value of 100 uF and a rating of 10 volts. The EC probably stands for electrolytic capacitor although that is not a standard designation. The  gray stripe usually identifies the positive terminal.

Answer (score 0):

That package type looks like a SOD (Small Outline Diode), so it is likely that that device is a zener diode for protection purposes.  You don't say what the device is, but it looks like it has audio connectors on the left hand side.  Having ESD protection of such a device would make sense.  You could check this out with a DMM in it's diode checker mode.